# Recursive search code optimization with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, optimization

I have created a little program to search a set of folders holding documents scanned.

the folder structure is as follows:

c:\images\year\month\date\documenttype\firstpartofdocumentNo.\

the year folder contains years from 2005 - 2015

the month folder contains the months of the year (Obviously)
same with date

the documenttype folder can contain between 1 and 5 folders

the firstpartofdocumentno. can contain between 1 and 3 folders

the code I am using at the moment is :

```
CompName = Environment.MachineName

    'MsgBox(CompName)

    TicketNo = TxtTicketNo.Text

    If CompName = "Comp1" Then
        ImageDir = "C:\Images\"
    Else
        ImageDir = "\\Comp1\Images\"
    End If

    For Each DirYear As String In Directory.GetDirectories(ImageDir)
        Dim YearInfo As New DirectoryInfo(DirYear)

        For Each DirMonth As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirYear)
            Dim MonthInfo As New DirectoryInfo(DirMonth)

            For Each DirDate As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirMonth)
                Dim DateInfo As New DirectoryInfo(DirDate)

                For Each DirType As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirDate)
                    Dim TypeInfo As New DirectoryInfo(DirType)

                    For Each DirStart As String In Directory.GetDirectories(DirType)
                        Dim StartInfo As New DirectoryInfo(DirStart)

                        MainDirectory = ImageDir & YearInfo.Name & "\" & MonthInfo.Name & "\" & DateInfo.Name & "\" & TypeInfo.Name & "\" & StartInfo.Name & "\"
                        'LstFiles.Items.Add(YearInfo.Name & "\" & MonthInfo.Name & "\" & DateInfo.Name & "\" & TypeInfo.Name & "\")
                        'Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(MainDirectory, TicketNo & "*")
                        'For Each Ticket As String In Directory.GetFiles(MainDirectory, TicketNo)
                        For Each Ticket As String In Directory.GetFiles(MainDirectory, TicketNo & "*")
                            LstFiles.Items.Add(Ticket)
                        Next

                        'Next


                    Next
                    'MsgBox(files)


                    'LstFiles.Items.Add()
                Next
                'LstFiles.Items.Add(dirInfo.Name)
            Next
        Next
        'MsgBox(ImageDir)
    Next
```

I have a textbox on the form which is used to enter the last four numbers of the ticketno and then this code runs when the button is clicked.

The problem is it can take up to five minutes to search, so I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this code to speed it up a bit or does this sound about right for searching that many folders.

Thanks in advance
  Gareth

Comment: This is a question for codereview.SE, not StackOverflow.

Comment: have you got a link for them